# Does select_tag always have to return something?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have two forms that leads to one controller action:

```
<%= form_tag some_action_path do %>
  <%= slect_tag 'foo[]', options_for_select([
                                  ["Nothing", nil],
                                  ["wal1", "wal1"],
                                  ["wal2", "wal2"]]) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag some_action_path do %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'foo[]', "wal1" %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'foo[]', "wal2" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

My problem is that when I select "Nothing" in select select_tag I get [""], on the other hand when I submit second form without any check_box selected I get nil. Which gives me a headake in my search function. Because it have to look like this:

```
    def search_action(foo)
      if foo.nil?
        Obj.all
      elsif foo.present? && foo[0].blank?
        Obj.all
      elsif foo.present? && foo[0].pesent?
        Obj.where(foo: foo)
      end
   end
```

The function above is irrelewent, I only wanted to show how the difference output between those two forms complicate my search action.

My question:

Is there any way to return nil from "select_tag" form? Or I am stupid to lead two forms to one controller action and one search method, and I should write two actions with two search action that leads to one view. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the search functionality is in one form where you have the both options available, but there is nothing wrong with your approach if you want them to be separate searches. Though I would rename the input of either of the forms to not be same as the other forms inputs to differentiate them on controller and then be able to write something like

```
def search_action(foo)
  if form_1_attribute.present?
    Obj.where(form_1_attribute: form_1_attribute)
  elsif form_2_attribute.present? && form_2_attribute.blank?
    Obj.where(form_2_attribute: form_2_attribute)
  else
    Obj.all
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't undestand why `if form_1_attribute.present? && form_1_attribute.present?` they are the same evaluations ? Idea with seperate iputs name may be a good idea.

Comment: @Kazik: You are absolutely right about that. Forgot it there by accident. Fixed now.